# Executing Basic Addition with for Loop (Trying to Understand how R Interprets for Loops)

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a vector named jvec that consists of #'s 1 - 9 and simply want to use a for loop to add 1 to every number in the vector if that number is bigger than 3 and print the result once.  I've tried this a number of ways and all have failed.

```
jvec <- c(1:9)
for (x in jvec) {
if (x > 3) {
x + 1
  }
}
print(jvec)
```

(won't work)

This won't work either:

```
jvec <- c(1:9)
for (x in jvec[c(x)]) {
if (jvec[c(x)] > 3) {
jvec[c(x)+1]
  print(jvec)
  }
}
```

Could someone please explain why neither of these options do the trick as well as how to do it correctly?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the index of `jvec` and update `jvec` only if the value is greater than 3.

```
jvec <- 1:9

for (x in seq_along(jvec)) {
  if (jvec[x] > 3) {
    jvec[x] <- jvec[x] + 1
  }
}

print(jvec)
#[1]  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

---

However, you can also do this without `for` loop :

```
jvec <- 1:9
jvec + as.integer(jvec > 3)
#[1]  1  2  3  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the same like in other programming languages - you have to actually assign your calculation results to a variable (to save it).

E.g. this would work (but there are also quicker ways in R):

```
jvec <- c(1:9)
for (i in 1:length(jvec)) {
  if (jvec[i] > 3) {
    jvec[i] <- jvec[i] + 1
  }
}
print(jvec)
```